# Linkedlist head node identifier/pointer access issue

Tags: php, c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

```
class LinkedList{
private $first;

public function Merge(LinkedList $ll){
//We can't access $ll->first for merging operation as it's private inside $ll.
//We can only access $this->first not $first of $ll
}
}
```

What could be the solution for this?

- Make $first public? that is not a nice idea
- Implement getter method for $first property

Can someone please suggest me correct way to access $first?

Comment: PHP doesn't allow you to access `$ll->first`???

Comment: @DeadMG, $ll is not equivalent to $this, so i can't access $ll->first

Comment: @DeadMG: Neither does C++, since `first` is declared under `private` access specifier.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++?

Comment: @Joachim, because answer would be same for PHP and C++, I have added C++ as linkedlist is very uncommon in PHP.

Comment: Making a simple test in C++, a public member function can access private members of another object from the same class. Is that not supposed to be possible?

Comment: @Fanael: Only as long as in member function of the `LinkedList` class since access specifiers operate on class basis and not object basis.

Comment: @Als: right, and now look in what scope OP's `Merge` function is defined.

Comment: @All, thanks...I can access private property of another object of same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is controlled though the class, not the instance. You can access any private member of a class from code that's within the class. Whether you use the `$this` reference or another doesn't matter.

```
class LinkedList{
    private $first="3.11";

    public function Merge(LinkedList $ll){
        echo $this->first, ' ', $ll->first;
    }   
}
```

This is the same in PHP, Java, and C++.